# Windows 10 "bash" alias was deleted...WSL is installed

Tags: linux, windows, command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Hello for some reason another installation meshed up my "bash" alias in the windows command prompt. Does anyone know how to bind it?

I have WSL installed and have been using it for the last year on my computer...now I can't access it

[bash stopped working despite having WSL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QeqO5.png)

Comment: Open `C:\Windows\System32` folder, did you see bash.exe there? If not then you've to re-install WSL feature.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find bash.exe in that directory and can launch it from there.